# How to run an object's method in twig without rendering what it returns

Tags: twig

In twig I have an object called attributes that contains a 'setAttribute' method. The function does what it's told but it returns a value that I don't want to render.

Here's the example

```
{{ attributes.setAttribute('angle', angle_position) }}
```

I've tried using {% instead of {{ like

```
{% attributes.setAttribute('angle', angle_position) %}
```

but that gives me a syntax error.

I've tried using comments to my advantage like so

```
<!--{{ attributes.setAttribute('angle', angle_position) }}-->
```

Which technically does work, but I don't necessarily want what is returned in the DOM even if it is commented out.

Is there a way I can use a method in my twig template and disregard what it returns?

Comment: That is precisely what I needed. If you like you can add an answer with that solution and I will mark it as answered. Or I can add it myself. Either way.

Comment: Just because there is a question that asks what the do tag does does not mean that is a duplicate question. That's like saying "What animal barks?" and "What do dogs do?" are the same question. If you didn't know the existence of one you're not going to find it searching for it.

Comment: Doesn't matter that much, if people stumble on this question they will see the related one. There is no need to delete this question just because it's closed as a dupe

Comment: Ahh gotcha that makes more sense. I thought closed questions eventually get deleted off the site or don't get indexed by google. If that's not the case that's reasonable.